# Минимизация количества аргументов функций

Tags: ооп, теория

Почти все титаны ООП в своих книгах сходятся во мнении, что чем меньше аргументов передается функции/методу, тем лучше. Идеально вообще без них, один - норм, два - уже не очень, три и больше - кошма-кошмар. И, в принципе, я с ними полностью согласен.

Тот же Роберт Мартин в "Чистом Коде" пишет:

> Другой вариант - преобразование `outputStrem` в поле текущего класса,
>   чтобы переменную не приходилось передавать при вызове.

Рассмотрим такой пример с применением этого совета (читать код не обязательно, суть описана ниже):

```
class GetCapacityTopFive
{
    const DEPTH          = 10;
    const SAMPLE_LENGTH  = 5;
    private $date;
    private $out;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->out  = [];
        $this->date = new DateTime();
    }

    public function calculate(): array {
        while (count($this->out) < self::DEPTH) {
            $this->date->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
            $this->addValueToOut();
        }
        ksort($this->out);

        return $this->out;
    }

    private function addValueToOut() {
        try {
            $this->out[] = $this->calculateValue();
        } catch (RuntimeException $e) {
            unset($e);
        }
    }

    private function calculateValue(): float {
        $data = $this->getSample();
        if ($data === []) throw new RuntimeException('Empty result');

        return array_sum($data) / self::SAMPLE_LENGTH;
    }

    private function getSample(): array {
        $result = CapacityApi::getMarginValuesForDate($this->date);
        sort($result);

        return array_slice($result, 0, self::SAMPLE_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

Цепочка вызовов такая:

```
calculate()
    ->addValueToOut()
    ->calculateValue()
    ->getSample()
    ->CapacityApi::getMarginValuesForDate($this->date)
```

Вроде идеальнее некуда, но режет глаз поле `$this->date`, которое:

1. По сути является глобальной переменной в области видимости класса, хранящей состояние. А работать с состоянием там, где можно обойтись без него - не самая лучшая практика.
2. Изменяется в начальном методе цепи вызова `calculate()`, а используется только один раз в конце цепи `CapacityApi::getMarginValuesForDate($this->date)`. Т.е. связь не то, чтоб очевидна.

Вполне логичным решением смотрится внесение `$this->date` в `calculate()` как локальную переменную и передавать ее каждой последующей:

```
calculate()
    ->addValueToOut($date)
    ->calculateValue($date)
    ->getSample($date)
    ->CapacityApi::getMarginValuesForDate($date)
```

Но мы тут-же превращаем три безаргументрых метода в унарные, причем аргумент им нужен только для того, чтобы передать его дальше. В общем печаль.

Хотелось бы услышать мнения знатоков, где я в этой цепи рассуждений порю чушь и как оно все на самом то деле?

Comment: @Abyx конкретно это PHP, но в контексте вопроса это совершенно не важно. Я могу переписать данный класс, например, на Java и суть вопроса не изменится.